# CSS grid make my photo rotate wen it display

Tags: html, css, image, grid

so I’ve been trying this all day, and been searching for documentation, but not luck – so here is my question.
I’m using grids in HTML and CSS for an art gallery.
I am displaying some photos that always appear the wrong way around even if they is properly rotated.
I have even tried to rotate them wrongly, so when it displays it will be on the right side.
But no luck, the photo always displays the wrong way around.
Here is my code, thank you guys for the help, I have searched in other questions to avoid duplicates but I have not found nothing.

[image]

---

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/d3fco/j7b745d8/

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(32, 206, 250, 0.445);
  width: 75%;
  height: 1000px;
  top: 11%;
  left: 22%
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 230px 230px 230px;
}
```

```html
<div id="filterbox"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div><img id="" src="img/master3d.jpg" width=100%;>mastergraff</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/example2.jpg" width=100%;>montrealquebec</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/mexample3.jpg" width=100%;>splash</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/backgroundtio.jpg" width=100%;>freestylee</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/furby.jpg" width=100%;>furbywizard</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/triplegraff.jpg" width=100%;>triplebanger</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/master3d.jpg" width=100%;>3d boss</div>
    <div><img id="" src="img/master3d.jpg" width=100%;>3d boss</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't show your issue. It might be with images themselves. *(think also about refreshing your page so modification are taken into account CTRL+R)*

Comment: i been refreshing :( haha

Comment: Never use local img src paths when posting on SO.

Comment: Your demo doesn't reproduce the problem. Where are the photos?